# how to display a custom post field value in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to display the specific custom field values in my custom post,i have used this code within the loop but still its not working
  can you anyone explain what is the problem?

Comment: Post your code, so that one can try finding out the issue in that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:-

```
<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'price', true); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As described [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta), you should be able to do

```
get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'something')
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but still the value is not displaying. This is my code <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<span> price:<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'price'); ?> </span>
<?php the_post_thumbnail();?>
<?php the_content(); ?>

<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<?php endif; ?> im using mysql

Comment: What's your database like for the post? Please edit and add to your question.

Comment: in your loop place the following code and show us the output: `<?php the_meta(); ?>`

Comment: ya i have tried the_meta() but its displaying all the custom field values, i need only specific value. Thanks for your quick response Mr.omar tariq

Comment: Is custom field key really 'price' and not something else?

Comment: yeah custom field key is price only.